# Power rule for limits negative power?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was trying to evaluate the limit
of $$\left(\frac1{x-a}\right)^{-1}$$ as $x$ approaches $a$, however I realized that the limit evaluates differently depending on whether the limit is taken first and then the power is taken into account, or vice versa.

How would I calculate the limit in this case?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\left[\left(\frac{1}{x-a}\right)^{-1}\right] = \lim\limits_{x\to a}\left[x-a\right] = 0$ noting that for all $x\neq a$ the inverse of the fraction is the fraction with the numerator and denominators swapped

Comment: And yes, $\lim\limits_{x\to a}[f(x)]$ does not necessarily equal $f(\lim\limits_{x\to a}[x])$.  That is a special circumstance when it does occur, namely "continuity."

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x))= f\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)\right) \;\iff \lim_{x\rightarrow l} f(x)\text{.   Exists }$$
Where l is $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$

Comment: I don’t understand how the expression I have asked about satisfies what you have written. The argument for f in the LHS does not exist.